# Conditionally Throw exception

Tags: java, exception

How do I make sure that some how it doesn't throw exception at first time while checking condition with 1 and allow to check all the condition and then throws the exception related to first Condition that "Number is already added".

```
class Hello
{
 List<Integer> newExample=new Arraylist<Integer>();
 List<Integer> example=new Arraylist<Integer>();
 example.add(1);
 example.add(2);
 example.add(3);
 public void addExample()
 {
  for(Integer ex: example)
   {
    pl.adding(ex);
   }
 }
 public void adding(Integer example)
 {
   if(example==1)//some work around so that rest of list of example (2,3) get chance to execute.
     { 
       throw new NumberAlreadyAddedException("Number is already added")
     }
   newExample.add(example);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. The `for` loop is defined outside of any method, `example` is undefined... And tbh I don't even understand your question - `allow to check all the condition`, what do you mean?

Comment: Example or Exam? This is unreadable and the question not understandable sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your case you should be checking for duplicate input at the point in time where you are receiving/adding the values to the list. I have slightly modified your code to do the check for a duplicate at the point where you are about to add the value to the List and if the value is found to be a duplicate, thrown an error immediately:

```
import java.util.*;

class Hello{

    List<Example> exam = new ArrayList<Example>();

    public void execute() throws Exception{
      add(1);
      add(2);
      add(3);
      add(1);

      for(Example ex:exam){
          test(ex)
      }
    }

    public void add(Integer value) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        if(exam.contains(value)){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number is already added.");
        }
        exam.add(value);

    }

    public void test(Example example){
        System.out.println("Running test on Example: " + example);//pl.test(ex);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Hello hello = new Hello();
      hello.add(1);
      hello.add(2);
      hello.add(3);
      hello.add(1);
    }
}

class Example{}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have implemented the same way but I am getting a problem ,If value(1,2,3) is in sorted order for example LinkedHashSet and at my first check if I am getting exception then my rest of value will not be exceuted(2,3). I want to excute rest of values after getting the exception.is there any work around.

Comment: Sure, you want to surround each time you add a new value with a try/catch. Catch the exception, print out the error and continue on. something like `try{ hello.add(1); }catch(Exception ex){ System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); } .. so on and so on.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on this site or tutorials on the web showing how to do 'java exception handling'